# Linking models to parent in Laravel

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is there a quick way to link models to a parent model?

For example, I have a `Product` model, where each row in the product table has a `product_type`.

I want to be able to access different product_types using their own model, and have access to the native query builder. E.g. I want to be able to access `Event` in the following way:

```
// Calling the Event model
Event::all();

// This would be equivalent to
Product::where('product_type', 'event')->get();

// Going deeper
Event::where('name', 'Some Title')->get();

// Should result in
Product::where('product_type', 'event')->where('name', 'Some Title')->get();
```

Is there a quick way of defining this relationship in the Event or Product models so that the query builder still works, other than manually redefining every single method in the Event model?

Comment: Keep in mind Laravel already has an Event so you will need to either change yours or namespace it.

Comment: Already done that, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid Laravel doesn't have really something for this out of the box, you could use scopes:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeEvents($query)
    {
        return $query->where('product_type', 'event');
    }

}
```

But you would have to use it this way:

```
Product::events()->where('name', 'Some Title')->get();
```

If this is not okay for you can easily create a class to help you with this:

```
<?php

class Event {

    private $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function all($columns = null) 
    {
        return $this->allEvents()->get($columns);
    }

    public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and') 
    {
        return $this->allEvents()->whereQuery($column, $operator, $value, $boolean);
    }

    private function allEvents() 
    {
        return $this->whereQuery('product_type', 'event');
    }

    private function whereQuery($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
    {
        return $this->product->where($column, $operator, $value, $boolean);
    }

}
```

You'll also need a Service Provider:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Product;

class EventsServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('events', function($app) {

            return new Event(new Product);

        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array('events');
    }

}
```

And a Facade:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class EventFacade extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'event'; }

}
```

Register your Service Provider and create an alias for the Facade all in your `app/config/app.php`:

```
'App\EventServiceProvider',

'Event' => 'App\EventFacade',
```

And then you'll be able to use it as you posted:

```
// Calling the Event model
Event::all();

// This would be equivalent to
Product::where('product_type', 'event')->get();

// Going deeper
Event::where('name', 'Some Title')->get();

// Should result in
Product::where('product_type', 'event')->where('name', 'Some Title')->get();
```

Note that you can go further and extend Eloquent or QueryBuilder and have all the functionalities of those guys or you can just create a Repository and put both Product and Event inside of it by just calling thinks like:

```
$repository->allProducts();
$repository->eventsByProduct(1);
```

So there are infinite possibilities and Laravel will not keep you attached to one or another, you just have to choose what's best for you.

Comment: That is one in-depth response! Quite well thought-out too, though I question the merit of such a system in the first place. Ignoring my personal feelings about the question though, this is well-answered!

Comment: By far and away the best answer I've seen on stack Overflow, and I'll accept it, so thank you.

Reading your response, I think the scope is probably the easiest way to go, so I'll stick with that.